# Fastest MySQL Engine for Extremely Large Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a "search engine"-esque website that I'm working on. During testing, the site searched through 40,000 entries in a traditional MySQL DB for a variety of different criteria, then sorts and displays each based on an overall rank. Performance was very good with this level of data, returning results in about 2-3 seconds on average.

Feeling confident, I increased the entries in the Database from 40,000 to roughly 325,000. Now, it takes about 4 minutes to search through the Database. A single search uses ~2GB of RAM! In addition, I get some warning messages from the server :)

I feel as though the code is as optimized as it can realistically get. If I worked on it for another month I might get 1% better performance. So my question is, what is the fastest open-source MySQL Engine to use for extremely large datasets/queries?

I've read about MemSQL, which looks awesome, except that it's not free (or even close to affordable). I don't know exact dollar figures but i've heard $5,000/license/server.

Any ideas, suggestions? Currently, I use MyISAM. I'm open to any alternative that is MySQL compatible.

I realize that at a certain point I'll need more powerful hardware, but at this point that solution is not in the cards.

Comment: 325,000 rows is not particularly large.  However, you provide no useful information to actually help with improving the performance.

Comment: I'm open to providing whatever information would be helpful. What would you need?

Comment: Sample queries, schema of tables, little bit of sample data, what the warning messages are, what indices you have on the tables would be a good start

Comment: Most of the time a database is slow because it's not properly designed. Your schema matters with millions of records because it impact file space, memory, etc. Choose the right field types for the data being stored, design appropriate indexes, etc. I develop applications that store between 10 and 100 million records using MySQL, so it's not always about just moving to a different server

Comment: I will update the post in just a minute with that data. Bear with me.

Comment: What do you search for, how do you structure and store that information? What size is your database? You might want highly pre-crunched entries that you can query with as little computing as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A database is not a search engine.

Trying to cajole it into one is asking for trouble down the road; especially considering databases are almost always doing dual duty.  So in addition to dealing with atomicity and ACID compliance, checking for consistency and manage transactions, you are now asking it to be a search engine as well.

You can fix the problems you are facing now easily (probably a case of adding indexes and tweaking the memory use; the [`EXPLAIN` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) is your friend) as your data set is very small but soon you will run into further problems.

There is a reason search engines aren't built on databases.

There are many options for you to chose from. The popular ones are [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for its pure search and indexing capability and [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) that is more of a platform for large distributed queries.

In my opinion the easiest one to understand is solr, which allows you to create a "Google" style search -that is search documents, create indexes, highlight matches. It integrates easily with databases. Try this [5 minute tutorial](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html) for an idea on how it works. Its an open source, Apache project.